# How to make an object follow your mouse in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to make an object to follow my mouse, but I don't know how to do this. If you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MouseMove` or `MouseClick` event of the form.
As follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        Label1.Location = e.Location
End Sub
```